# Paraboloid inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Where is the region of this inequality $x^2+y^2\geq 3z$. Is it outside or inside the paraboloid and how to prove it (above or below) I have taken some points but didn't really work.

Comment: What does "inside" mean? Does it mean that $z>\frac13(x^2+y^2)$?

Comment: In math, inside usually refers to the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)). Perhaps you are rather referring to the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: The surface $\;3z=x^2+y^2\implies z=\frac13\left(x^2+y^2\right)\;$ is an upwards bowl-like one (with vertex at the origin), and the set of all points $\;z<\frac13\left(x^2+y^2\right)\;$ is BELOW this surface...So you are between the "floor" (the plane $\;z=0$) and the above bowl in the upper half space $\;z\ge0\;$, and all the lower half space $\;z<0\;$ .

Comment: Consistent with the previous comments, it is perhaps easier to visualize the **complement** of the desired set.  As indicated, if you imagine an upwards **bowl-like** shape, the complement of the desired set would be all points $~(x,y,z)~$ that are **strictly interior** to the bowl.